# Outlook 2013 Add-in not loaded after installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield, outlook-addin

I have developed one add-in using Outlook 2010 AddIn for outlook 2013 with visual studio 2012. I have developed User Controls and worked with Custom Task Pane in Add In.

It works perfectly when I debug add-in from visual studio. I have created setup file using Install Shield Limited Edition (following basic steps given by forum).  However, if I install that add-in and open Outlook, Add In does not load and is not visible on Home tab. Nothing happen.

I haven't made any registry entry while building setup file.

Please let me know how can i make it working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make an entry to Registry. You can simply do through Install shield program.

Here is the quick screen shot:

[image]

Make sure that the loadBehaviour is set to 3.
If there is any error in the addon on load then it will set to back to 0.

It has been long time I did not developed the addon but I am sure my information is correct.

Also make sure that the you look after for 64 vs 32 bits entry.

I found a quick link for you too: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeamsgdev/archive/2013/11/21/outlook-deploying-an-outlook-2013-add-in-using-installshield-le.aspx

Comment: Thank you codebased for quick reply, i will do it and let you know if any.